# Graph Drawing: Radial Layout with given node radii and non-straight edges

Tags: networkx, graph-theory, graphviz, graph-drawing

I want to draw the [lattice of subgroups](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_of_subgroups) up to a finite subgroup index of an infinite, discrete space group with a graph drawing tool such as [yEd](https://www.yworks.com/products/yed#yed-support-resources), [GraphViz](https://graphviz.org/), [NetworkX](https://networkx.org), ...

**An Example input file**
would be following [`graphml`](http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/) file for the two-dimensional space group *p4gm* up to index 8 (generated by self-written code in [gap](https://www.gap-system.org/)):

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<graphml
      xmlns='http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns'
      xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
      xsi:schemaLocation='http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns
      http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns/1.0/graphml.xsd'>

  <key id='idx' for='node' attr.name='index'  attr.type='int'    />
  <key id='r'   for='node' attr.name='radius' attr.type='double' />

  <key id='idx' for='edge' attr.name='index'  attr.type='int'    />

  <graph id='G' edgedefault='directed'>
    <node id='01'> <data key='idx'>1</data> <data key='r'>0.</data> </node>
    <node id='02'> <data key='idx'>2</data> <data key='r'>0.33333333333333337</data> </node>
    <node id='03'> <data key='idx'>2</data> <data key='r'>0.33333333333333337</data> </node>
    <node id='04'> <data key='idx'>2</data> <data key='r'>0.33333333333333337</data> </node>
    <node id='05'> <data key='idx'>4</data> <data key='r'>0.66666666666666674</data> </node>
    <node id='06'> <data key='idx'>4</data> <data key='r'>0.66666666666666674</data> </node>
    <node id='07'> <data key='idx'>6</data> <data key='r'>0.8616541669070521</data> </node>
    <node id='08'> <data key='idx'>4</data> <data key='r'>0.66666666666666674</data> </node>
    <node id='09'> <data key='idx'>4</data> <data key='r'>0.66666666666666674</data> </node>
    <node id='10'> <data key='idx'>4</data> <data key='r'>0.66666666666666674</data> </node>
    <node id='11'> <data key='idx'>4</data> <data key='r'>0.66666666666666674</data> </node>
    <node id='12'> <data key='idx'>4</data> <data key='r'>0.66666666666666674</data> </node>
    <node id='13'> <data key='idx'>6</data> <data key='r'>0.8616541669070521</data> </node>
    <node id='14'> <data key='idx'>8</data> <data key='r'>1.</data> </node>
    <node id='15'> <data key='idx'>8</data> <data key='r'>1.</data> </node>
    <node id='16'> <data key='idx'>8</data> <data key='r'>1.</data> </node>
    <node id='17'> <data key='idx'>8</data> <data key='r'>1.</data> </node>
    <node id='18'> <data key='idx'>8</data> <data key='r'>1.</data> </node>
    <node id='19'> <data key='idx'>8</data> <data key='r'>1.</data> </node>
    <node id='20'> <data key='idx'>8</data> <data key='r'>1.</data> </node>
    <node id='21'> <data key='idx'>8</data> <data key='r'>1.</data> </node>
    <node id='22'> <data key='idx'>8</data> <data key='r'>1.</data> </node>
    <node id='23'> <data key='idx'>8</data> <data key='r'>1.</data> </node>
    <node id='24'> <data key='idx'>8</data> <data key='r'>1.</data> </node>
    <node id='25'> <data key='idx'>8</data> <data key='r'>1.</data> </node>
    <node id='26'> <data key='idx'>8</data> <data key='r'>1.</data> </node>

    <edge id='e01' target='02' source='01'> <data key='idx'>2</data> </edge>
    <edge id='e02' target='03' source='01'> <data key='idx'>2</data> </edge>
    <edge id='e03' target='04' source='01'> <data key='idx'>2</data> </edge>
    <edge id='e04' target='05' source='02'> <data key='idx'>2</data> </edge>
    <edge id='e05' target='06' source='02'> <data key='idx'>2</data> </edge>
    <edge id='e06' target='07' source='02'> <data key='idx'>3</data> </edge>
    <edge id='e07' target='06' source='03'> <data key='idx'>2</data> </edge>
    <edge id='e08' target='08' source='03'> <data key='idx'>2</data> </edge>
    <edge id='e09' target='06' source='04'> <data key='idx'>2</data> </edge>
    <edge id='e10' target='10' source='04'> <data key='idx'>2</data> </edge>
    <edge id='e11' target='11' source='04'> <data key='idx'>2</data> </edge>
    <edge id='e12' target='09' source='04'> <data key='idx'>2</data> </edge>
    <edge id='e13' target='12' source='04'> <data key='idx'>2</data> </edge>
    <edge id='e14' target='13' source='04'> <data key='idx'>3</data> </edge>
    <edge id='e15' target='14' source='05'> <data key='idx'>2</data> </edge>
    <edge id='e16' target='15' source='05'> <data key='idx'>2</data> </edge>
    <edge id='e17' target='14' source='06'> <data key='idx'>2</data> </edge>
    <edge id='e18' target='16' source='06'> <data key='idx'>2</data> </edge>
    <edge id='e19' target='17' source='06'> <data key='idx'>2</data> </edge>
    <edge id='e20' target='18' source='06'> <data key='idx'>2</data> </edge>
    <edge id='e21' target='16' source='08'> <data key='idx'>2</data> </edge>
    <edge id='e22' target='19' source='08'> <data key='idx'>2</data> </edge>
    <edge id='e23' target='18' source='09'> <data key='idx'>2</data> </edge>
    <edge id='e24' target='20' source='09'> <data key='idx'>2</data> </edge>
    <edge id='e25' target='14' source='10'> <data key='idx'>2</data> </edge>
    <edge id='e26' target='16' source='11'> <data key='idx'>2</data> </edge>
    <edge id='e27' target='21' source='11'> <data key='idx'>2</data> </edge>
    <edge id='e28' target='22' source='11'> <data key='idx'>2</data> </edge>
    <edge id='e29' target='23' source='11'> <data key='idx'>2</data> </edge>
    <edge id='e30' target='18' source='12'> <data key='idx'>2</data> </edge>
    <edge id='e31' target='21' source='12'> <data key='idx'>2</data> </edge>
    <edge id='e32' target='24' source='12'> <data key='idx'>2</data> </edge>
    <edge id='e33' target='25' source='12'> <data key='idx'>2</data> </edge>
    <edge id='e34' target='26' source='12'> <data key='idx'>2</data> </edge>

  </graph>
</graphml>
```

I have anonymous-ed the data to focus on the graph drawing.

I am looking for a graph drawing tool which can layout the nodes on a radial layout, similar to a [radial tree](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radial_tree) but can draw non-straight edges to avoid edge-node crossings. Edge-edge crossing are fine. Ideally however, a viewer can follow each edge from source to target node.

**yEd** (3.22)
provides a [*radial layout*](https://www.yworks.com/pages/drawing-radial-diagrams) which can draw edges as arcs or curved to avoid edge-node crossings:

[image]

However, the nodes are placed on the same concentric circle based on the shortest distance to the center, measured by number of traversed edges.

But I want to place the nodes based on their subgroup index (to be precise the logarithm of the index). In the above picture the nodes with index 6 are on the same circle as the nodes with index 4 which is not what I want.

**NetworkX** (2.8.4)
has the [*shell layout*](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.layout.shell_layout.html) which allows you to assign manually the nodes to the shells

```py
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import log

G = nx.read_graphml("ITC_2_012_idx8.graphml")

indices = set([idx for n, idx in G.nodes.data('index')])
radii = [log(idx)/log(max(indices)) for n, idx in G.nodes.data('index')]
shells = [[n for n, idx in G.nodes.data('index') if idx == x] for x in indices]
pos = nx.shell_layout(G, shells)

plt.box(False) # remove box

nx.draw_networkx(G, pos,
                 node_color="white",
                 node_size=500,
                 edgecolors="black",
                 labels={n: idx for n, idx in G.nodes.data('index')},
                )
```

[image]

However, NetworkX draws only straight edges.

Can GraphViz or another graph drawing tool do what I want?

I have started to create an own layouting and edge routing algorithm which results in following style of drawing:

[image]

However, this is unfinished and becomes a never ending story. So I am hoping that I have overlooked a tool which can give automatically the desired radial layout and suitable edge routes.
yEd is the closest tool I have come by (see the first picture of this question).

Comment: You can also draw curved arrows with Networkx by passing `connectionstyle='arc3,rad=0.2'` to your `nx.draw_networkx` function (doc [here](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx_edges.html)). By adjusting the `rad` value, you might be able to get the configuration you want.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. First this is a shared option for all edges, a list/dict is not allowed. But most importantly, I need an algorithm which decides how to draw edges. E.g. the edges from the root node should be straight, only in the outer shells arcs are necessary and they should have bends in both directions. The given yEd pic illustrates this very clearly. Also specifying edge routes manually is really time consuming for larger subgroup indices and space groups with large number of maximal subgroups to achieve a non-chaotic picture.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I love your solution to the edge routing, and would love to see the code for that.

Secondly, below is my attempt using netgraph, which is a network visualisation library I wrote (and maintain).
Netgraph is easily installable (`pip install netgraph`), and accepts `Graph` objects from various network analysis libraries (networkx, igraph, graph-tool), so there shouldn't be any friction.

[image]

The `shell` node layout uses the so-called median heuristic to order the nodes within a layer to reduce edge crossings.
The `curved` edge layout uses a variant of the Fruchterman-Reingold algorithm to distribute the edge control points such that edges avoid nodes (and each other) -- where possible.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx

from netgraph import Graph # pip install netgraph


# from the question:
G = nx.read_graphml("tmp/test.graphml")
indices = set([idx for n, idx in G.nodes.data('index')])
shells = [[n for n, idx in G.nodes.data('index') if idx == x] for x in indices]
radii = [np.log(idx)/np.log(max(indices)) for n, idx in G.nodes.data('index')]
node_labels = {n: idx for n, idx in G.nodes.data('index')}

# define a bounding box for the node layout
max_radius = np.max(radii)
origin = (-max_radius, -max_radius)
scale = (2 * max_radius, 2 * max_radius)

# initialise a figure
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 8))

# indicate shells
radii = np.unique(radii)
for radius in radii[::-1]:
    ax.add_patch(plt.Circle((0, 0), radius=radius, facecolor='white', edgecolor='lightgray'))

# plot graph on top
g = Graph(G,
          node_size=6,
          edge_width=2,
          node_labels=node_labels,
          node_layout='shell',
          node_layout_kwargs=dict(shells=shells, radii=radii),
          edge_layout='curved',
          edge_layout_kwargs=dict(k=0.05), # larger values -> straighter edges
          origin=origin,
          scale=scale,
          arrows=True,
          ax=ax
)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have not been aware of [netgraph](https://github.com/paulbrodersen/netgraph). I like that it uses a measure to reduce edge crossings. But edge crossings are not as critical as edge-node crossings which exists in your answer. E.g an edge from a node with index 4 crossing the side to a node with index 8 goes directly through another node with index 4 which can very easily misinterpreted.

Answer (score 0):

#### NetworkX `shell_layout` for node positions & GraphViz `neato` for edge routing

`Neato` is chosen because it respects the graphviz node attribute [`pos`](https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/pos/) in combination with [`pin`](https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/pin/).

With [`splines`](https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/splines/) edge routing and the attribute [`esep`](https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/esep/), edge-node crossings can be avoided.

```py
import networkx as nx
import pygraphviz as pgv
from math import log

G = nx.read_graphml('ITC_2_012_idx8.graphml')

indices = set([idx for n, idx in G.nodes.data('index')])
radii = [log(idx)/log(max(indices)) for n, idx in G.nodes.data('index')]
shells = [[n for n, idx in G.nodes.data('index') if idx == x] for x in indices]
pos = nx.shell_layout(G, shells)

A = nx.nx_agraph.to_agraph(G)

A.graph_attr['splines'] = 'spline' # or 'polyline'
A.graph_attr['scale'] = '0.6'
A.graph_attr['esep'] = '0.5' # node-edge distance
A.node_attr['shape'] = 'circle'
A.node_attr['pin'] = 'true'
for k in A.nodes():
    n = A.get_node(k)
    n.attr['label'] = str(n.attr['index']) # add label 
    n.attr['pos'] = str(pos[k][0]*10)+','+str(pos[k][1]*10)+'!' # set pos string 
    
# print(A.to_string())

A.layout() # default 'neato' which respects the node attribute 'pos'
A # rich output in Jupyter Notebook/Lab using pygraphviz 1.9, Feb 2022
```

[image]

The edge-node crossings are gone.

However, this solution is not yet as I would like to have it:
I would prefer inbound and outbound edges are docked at the nodes on opposite sites (except root node).
yEd radial layout with edge routing does this or see my low-res self-made layout and routes.

#### Update: Enforce [`tailport`](https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/tailport/)

```py
import networkx as nx
import pygraphviz as pgv
from math import atan2, log, pi

G = nx.read_graphml("ITC_2_012_idx8.graphml")
indices = set([int(idx) for n, idx in G.nodes.data('index')])
radii = [log(idx)/log(max(indices)) for n, idx in G.nodes.data('index')]
shells = [[n for n, idx in G.nodes.data('index') if idx == x] for x in indices]
pos = nx.shell_layout(G, shells)

A = nx.nx_agraph.to_agraph(G)

pos_factor = 12
A.graph_attr['scale'] = "0.5"
A.graph_attr['esep'] = "1"
A.graph_attr['splines'] = "spline"
A.node_attr['shape'] = "circle"
A.node_attr['pin'] = "true"
A.edge_attr['arrowhead']="vee"
for k in A.nodes():
    k.attr["label"] = str(k.attr["index"]) 
    k.attr["pos"] = str(pos[k][0]*pos_factor)+','+str(pos[k][1]*pos_factor)+"!" 

# Set 'tailport' based on quadrant of tail node 
for n1, n2 in A.edges():
    if n1 == A.nodes()[0]: # skip root edges
        continue
    e = A.get_edge(n1, n2)
    theta = atan2(pos[n1][1], pos[n1][0])/pi*180.
    
    if -22.5 <= theta < 22.5:
        e.attr["tailport"] = 'e'
    elif 22.5 <= theta < 67.5:
        e.attr["tailport"] = 'ne'
    elif 67.5 <= theta < 112.5:
        e.attr["tailport"] = 'n'
    elif 112.5 <= theta < 157.5:
        e.attr["tailport"] = 'nw'
    elif 157.5 <= theta <= 180. or -157.5 > theta > -180.:
        e.attr["tailport"] = 'w'
    elif -157.5 <= theta <= -112.5:
        e.attr["tailport"] = 'sw'
    elif -112.5 <= theta <= -67.5:
        e.attr["tailport"] = 's'
    elif -67.5 <= theta <= -22.5:
        e.attr["tailport"] = 'se'
    else:
        raise ValueError('Quadrant determination failed for node', n1,
                         'with polar angle', theta)
    
# Mark problematic edges
A.get_edge('10', '14').attr["color"] = "red"
A.get_edge('04', '06').attr["color"] = "blue"
A.get_edge('06', '18').attr["color"] = "orange"

A.layout() # default 'neato'
A
```

[image]

However, IMHO the visualisation does not become clearer (easy to grasp the connectivity) since some highly curved edges (e.g. red one) are introduced and there are parallel edge overlaps (e.g. blue and orange).

Answer (score -1):

Graphviz has two radial-ish layout engines: circo & twopi.  Both allow *desired* edge length to be set using the **len** attribute.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I want to fix nodes on certain circles. Adjusting the edge length does not ensure this. Actually, the edge length varies. I do not have a tree.

Comment: You can effectively set distance from center by setting len of an edge (possibly invisible) from the root node OR you can add N invisible intermediate nodes and edges

Comment: According to https://graphviz.org/pdf/dot.1.pdf is the option **len**, specific to the layouts _neato_ and _fdp_ but not _circo_ and _twopi_.

Comment: Sorry, my blunder.  It looks like twopi is best candidate, I'll investigate some more.